# How many gray levels Matlab can show?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Let's say I have a Matrix `Image` of `uint16`.

Where basically each pixel can range from `0` to `65535`.

If I display this image with `imshow(Image)` How many levels of gray Matlab will render?

The standard `255` levels (thus implicitly converting the image to uint8)?
(Please note I know I can change the colormap, but I would like to know only the number of gray levels )

Comment: Using `imtool` you can easily adjust that range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of the colormap tells you how many colors (or gray levels, in this case) Matlab is trying to display.

```
numGrayLevels = size(get(gcf,'Colormap'),1)
```

Note that most monitors only support 8-bits of gray. And depending on the quality and calibration of the display you may be seeing far less than that.

Comment: From this you'll see that by default the colormaps in Matlab use only 64 colors rather 256 (don't ask me why this is still the case in 2014). To get smoother color gradations you can set the colormap manually via `map = colormap(gray(256));`.

Answer (score 5):

This can be a more complex answer than that.  Most computers can ONLY DISPLAY 256 shades of gray currently.

MATLAB is NOT going to be able to do any better than that.  However, using pseudo-coloring schemes, you may be able to get MATLAB to REPRESENT the full 16 bits per pixel in which case it will be displaying upwards of the 65535 colors you choose in your color scale.

Comment: @link - where did you read that, youve struck my interest :-)  Even if the actual pixel did support that, most graphics chips themselves that drive them only support up to 24 bit true color (which is only 256 shades of gray).  When we see 32 bit, normally (and almost always) that means the addition of an alpha channel, not more colors).

Comment: @llnk - Sorry, just noticed the question mark :-)  Im pretty darn sure it does not support larger than 256 gray shades.  I have thus far seen no evidence of that.

Comment: Some cheap LCD screens may not even have eight bits. It shouldn't hurt to specify a higher depth colormap other than that it take up more memory and require more processing. It may not have an effect except on highly specialized displays (those used by radiologists for example) provided that Matlab doesn't get in the way. I suppose that it could be incompatible with some poorly-written functions.

Comment: @horchler - I think that PHYSICALLY it is important to note that the human eye really has no ability to distinguish better than 256 shades of any one color element.  We are most sensitive to green and even that one, 256 is beyond our eyes capability.  That IS why systems have been designed the way they are today.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think any limit is enforced by Matlab. RGB and HSV color values can also be doubles - giving you a "near infinite" number of colors (and also grays).

The plot windows are done in Java. There the color can be defined by four floats (see [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)) - leaving you still with a more colors than hardware can handle.

Help states:

> The actual color used in rendering depends on finding the best match given the color space  available for a particular output device.

So in the end it seems to depend on your hardware.